# SSRS Report as Web View

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hi i create a report in SSRS and i want to deploy as a web base so any one can view report with one HTTP link can any one tell me how can i do that?

Some one said i need Sharepoint and someone said NO u just need IIS install in ur pc and it will work please help  me out this Thanks.

•   Exactly What type of Storage is required  - Local or Network?
•   How will these SSSRS reports be generated? 
•   How will Live data reports be uploaded. Can Data see the network locations or does it need to be Local ?

Comment: Is this for the real Internet or an Intranet?  SSRS Report server comes with SQL server and serves up web pages with the reports on them, if it's intranet. If it's for the Internet, how up to date does it need to be?

Comment: looking for both and update will daily basis

Comment: I would advise using the SSRS Report itself for internal users. Then set up a File Subscription to a DMZ machine that can serve up files (maybe via IIS/HTML links). I would not advise making the SSRS Server visible to the outside intranet. One exception would be if you had clients you wanted to grant very limited VPN access to look at certain reports.